# xelatex doesn't load language symbols

Tags: languages

Maybe you can help me to fix this problem? My code is:

```
\documentclass[%
    paper=A4,                   % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
    twoside=true,               % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,                  % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=full,               % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,         % prefix for chapter marks
    11pt,                       % font size
    headings=normal,            % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,         % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,               % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,               % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,        % display table captions above the float env
    draft=false,                % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}%
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % defines file's character encoding
\usepackage[lithuanian]{babel} % babel system, adjust the language of the content
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
 \selectlanguage{lithuanian}

\usepackage[                    % clean thesis style
    figuresep=colon,%
    sansserif=false,%
    hangfigurecaption=false,%
    hangsection=true,%
    hangsubsection=true,%
    colorize=full,%
    colortheme=bluemagenta,%
    bibsys=bibtex,%
    bibfile=bib-refs,%
    bibstyle=alphabetic,%
]{cleanthesis}

\hypersetup{                    % setup the hyperref-package options
    pdftitle={\thesisTitle},    %   - title (PDF meta)
    pdfsubject={\thesisSubject},%   - subject (PDF meta)
    pdfauthor={\thesisName},    %   - author (PDF meta)
    plainpages=false,           %   -
    colorlinks=false,           %   - colorize links?
    pdfborder={0 0 0},          %   -
    breaklinks=true,            %   - allow line break inside links
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     %
    bookmarksopen=true          %
}
\begin {document}
ąčęėįšųū
\end{document}
```

I am also using cleanthesis 0.3.1. I am getting error: *command \nobreakspace  unavailable in encoding T1*

I fixed this problem, by putting in my preamble, but symbols are still not loading:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ul9}
\xpatchcmd{\ttfamily}{\selectfont}{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}{}{}
\DeclareTextCommand{\nobreakspace}{T1}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
```

Maybe I miss something?

Comment: Your snippet is rather useless, we can't test your issue with it, make a complete small example. (But don't load inputenc with xelatex).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just tested it is working, but when I try to use it with cleanthesis package it starts to not load my language symbols, maybe you can advise me something?

Comment: I already gave you an advise: I asked you do provide a complete example. Why did you ignore it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer okey, I added it :)

Comment: As it stands, `cleanthesis` cannot be used with XeLaTeX without substantial changes

Comment: @egreg about what changes you are talking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend cleanthesis. It loads a number of packages which are not recommended together with a KOMA-class. Also the page layout is buggy.

If you insist to use it:

- cleanthesis changes the font encoding to something unsuitable for xelatex. So one has to reset the font encoding.
- Don't load inputenc.
- Use biber with xelatex. bibtex can break with utf8.
- There are some font definitions which perhaps need a redefinition.
- It is quite possible that cleanthesis contains more code not suitable for xelatex.
- Don't use babel with your language, the language file is not adapted to an unicode-engine.

Here is something that could work

```
    \documentclass[%
    paper=A4,                   % paper size --> A4 is default in Germany
    twoside=true,               % onesite or twoside printing
    openright,                  % doublepage cleaning ends up right side
    parskip=full,               % spacing value / method for paragraphs
    chapterprefix=true,         % prefix for chapter marks
    11pt,                       % font size
    headings=normal,            % size of headings
    bibliography=totoc,         % include bib in toc
    listof=totoc,               % include listof entries in toc
    titlepage=on,               % own page for each title page
    captions=tableabove,        % display table captions above the float env
    draft=false,                % value for draft version
]{scrreprt}%
%    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % don't use with xelatex


\usepackage{polyglossia} % babel-lithuaninan is not adapted to xelatex
\setdefaultlanguage{lithuanian}


\usepackage[                    % clean thesis style
    figuresep=colon,%
    sansserif=false,%
    hangfigurecaption=false,%
    hangsection=true,%
    hangsubsection=true,%
    colorize=full,%
    colortheme=bluemagenta,%
    bibsys=biber,% changed
    bibfile=bib-refs,%
    bibstyle=alphabetic,%
]{cleanthesis}
%
%reset font encoding after cleanthesis:
\usepackage[EU1]{fontenc}
%
%redefined
\renewcommand{\helv}{\sffamily\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\book}{\rmfamily\fontseries{m}\fontsize{11}{13}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\tgherosfont}{\sffamily\selectfont}
%
%
%temporarly commented as commands are undefined in MWE:
%\hypersetup{                    % setup the hyperref-package options 
%%    pdftitle={\thesisTitle},    %   - title (PDF meta)
%%    pdfsubject={\thesisSubject},%   - subject (PDF meta)
%%    pdfauthor={\thesisName},    %   - author (PDF meta)
%    plainpages=false,           %   -
%    colorlinks=false,           %   - colorize links?
%    pdfborder={0 0 0},          %   -
%    breaklinks=true,            %   - allow line break inside links
%    bookmarksnumbered=true,     %
%    bookmarksopen=true          %
%}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt} %page layout is buggy, line overwrites text
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A} 
ąčęėįšųū \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help :) I don't like this package either, but I want to make my document file look like example in clean thesis(I mean the header and footer). Maybe you can offer me how I can do it without clean thesis?